# Equality of a list of classes

Tags: scala

I am trying to compare two Lists containing case classes. Can't figure out which method to override to get this working. Please refer to the code below.

```
trait Filter {
  def toQueryString: String
}
trait SimpleFilter extends Filter {
  val key: String
  val value: Any

  override def toQueryString = value match {
    case v: String => s"$key='$v'"
    case _         => s"$key=$value"
  }
  override def toString = "$key:$value"

  override def equals(that: Any) = {
    that match {
      case s: SimpleFilter => {
        key == key && value == value
      }
      case _ => false
    }
  }
  override def hashCode() = key.hashCode + value.hashCode
}

class DestinationFilter(override val value: String) extends SimpleFilter {
  override val key = "destination"
}
object DestinationFilter {
  def apply(value: String) = new DestinationFilter(value)
}

object Tester {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val d1 = DestinationFilter("Google")
    val d2 = DestinationFilter("Google")
    val l1 = List(d1)
    val l2 = List(d2)
    println(11 == 12)
    println(d1 == d2)
  }

}
```

which returns

```
false
true
```

Can't understand why the list comparison returns false. Ultimately what I want is this to be equal

```
List(DestinationFilter("Amazon"), LocationFilter("Yahoo"), DestinationFilter("Google") == List(DestinationFilter("Yahoo"), LocationFilter("Amazon"), DestinationFilter("Google")
```

*they should be equal irrespective of order.

Comment: Aside from the inevitable technical answer...read this: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/187457/what-is-the-principle-of-least-astonishment

Comment: you have not case class in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your comparison, `11` and `12` should be `l1` and `l2`:

```
println(l1 == l2) // true
```

So `11 == 12` is always false, you're just comparing `Int`s.

You also need to change your `equals` override, your just comparing `key` and `value` to themselves, which is always true:

```
  override def equals(that: Any) = {
      that match {
        case s: SimpleFilter =>
          key == s.key && value == s.value //edited
        case _ => false
      }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out:)…. side effect of working very late in office :(

Comment: @user007 Update your equals method too, should work for what you want, though list order will interfere with the equality you're looking for.